# Show Real-Time Users in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I can import a lot of data from [Analytics](https://analytics.google.com) to [Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com), but I can't find "**Real-Time**" data.

How to show on **Data Studio** how many users are online right now on my site?

[image]

Comment: The only way for now is to click on the refresh icon in the report to get the updated numbers. I have automated the functionality of clicking the refresh button and the script runs in cloud each minute(for my report only). Which means that my communal screen always show the updated numbers.

Comment: While this question **Needs Details or Charity** it could also be considered **Not about Programming or Software Development** as it's about Google Analytics in a Non-Programming context. It may be a better fit on a different Stack Exchange site, such as [Webmasters.SE] or [Webapps.SE] (though check with the respective site FAQs and general questions asked there before posting).

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics real time data is not supported yet.

Comment: Does it mean its not supported in the beta only, but works later?

Comment: Not supported, but there are many workarounds. Even in 2013 there been published an article about it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to get real time data in data Studio.
You need to use google analytics Real time API, a little google sheet.

Fetch the data in google sheet with real time api and use this as a data source in data studio.

Google sheet data can be refreshed automatically with setting the time driven trigger. But in data studio you need to click the refresh data button every time you need the real time data.